# Android WebView contained in a Library Project - API Key use?

Tags: android

I have 2 projects: first is a library project which contains many activities/layouts/etc, second is a regular android project which will use this library project's stuff.

the library project contains a `WebView`, and I wish to show the activity's view containing this web view in my regular Android project.

The library project has the potential to be included in many different android projects.

**My question:
Do I have to change the WebView's API Key in the Library Project every time I export the Android project to an APK, or can I use a constant API Key for all projects including the Library?**

Extra thoughts:
Ideally I would not like to be changing things in the library project that relate to a specific android project.  If I have to make a change to the Library project, I'd have to create and put in place a new WebView API Key for every project containing this library(if I wanted to update the app in the market), and that could potentially be a pain in the butt.